# Fastlane building UI test target

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I have problems building the UI test target with Fastlane. It builds directly the normal target of the app. Anyone faced that?

Comment: We need more information to really help you. What kind of problems are you facing? What does the lane look like that you're trying to execute?